# Azure Spatial Anchors - How to save and get anchors

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk, azure-spatial-anchors

I tried the azure-spatial-anchor-demo-package and it worked fine for me. Now I wanted to use azure in my project. In my current understanding, the coordinates of the anchor are stored. More precise information about whether it is a 3D object, and what it looks like, is not stored. If I'm wrong about this, please correct me.

Lets say I have 3 different objects: a car, house and tree.

All of them are anchors, which I instantiate in my scene. My current procedure is as follows:

1. `_anchorModul.StartAzureSession();`
2. I instantiate a car, house and tree and call for each of them `CreateAzureAnchor();`:

   ```
   InstantiatedGo = Instantiate(GoToInstantiate, GetCurrentHitPosition(), Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.back, _gazeProvider.HitInfo.normal)) as GameObject;
   _anchorModul.CreateAzureAnchor(InstantiatedGo);
   ```
3. In the method `CreateAzureAnchor()` I set the type of my object via `localCloudAnchor.AppProperties.Add("type", theObject.GetComponent<SomeClass>().Type);`.
4. After that I save the anchors to disk via `_anchorModul.SaveAzureAnchorIdToDisk();`

But now I want to restart my application and get the objects at the right position. The right [order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-asa-ch2) should be:

1. Restart the application.
2. Get Azure Anchor from Disk
3. Start Azure Session
4. Find Azure Anchor

**My Question**: How do I get the found anchors, so I can access the properties I set and instantiate the related properties on my three objects?

**My Specs**:

- Unity 2019.2.15
- MRTK 2.2
- AzureSpatialAnchors.unitypackage
- MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.2.0.0.unitypackage
- MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.2.0.1.unitypackage

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a request to the Azure service to [locate an anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/create-locate-anchors-unity?WT.mc_id=github-mixedrealitycurriculum-ayyonet#locate-a-cloud-spatial-anchor) using at least one of the ids saved. You can either send an array of ids or send one and ask for the nearby anchors.

Comment: sorry, still didnt check up on this. As soon as I work on that project again, I will try it out and give feedback!